# Spring webAppContextSetup does not recognize controllers mappings

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

My unit test fails when testing a controller. I am getting a 404 when expecting a 200 status code. I suppose the webAppContextSetup does not recognize controllers. 
Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
public class MyControllerTest
{
 @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

 mockMvc.perform(get("/locales?limit=1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

The message is  "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/locales] in DispatcherServlet with name ''"

This works in the real application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding component scan for the package which contains controllers:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)
@ComponentScan("x.y.z")
```